# Vulnerability: Standalone Library vs. Same Code Elsewhere

Tags: web-application, vulnerability, appsec, vulnerability-management

Are libraries inherently more vulnerable than in-house application code?

The speaker of [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gt6tough35c) generally advises folks against creating wrapper libraries for Erlang in Elixir rather than just writing the code in Erlang. One of the reasons he gives is vulnerabilities and I'm not sure I follow.

Say you have some code that computes isEven. You can either just write that code in Erlang or you can write it in Elixir and turn it into a library. Given that library stays the same forever (people don't keep adding to it), the surface area for vulnerabilities feels like it would remain the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: The way you package code doesn't make it more or less secure unless different ways imply different hardening options, e.g. compiler flags. But then I recall RPC and it all becomes moot.

Answer (score 1):

It is an important topic, but it depends on so many factors, that making a definitive generic answer is difficult. You have to take into consideration:

Does your development team have enough people, the technical ability and time to reimplement such code?

If the answer is close to no, then you should stick with libraries. But if yes, you could choose a quantified balance between handling house-made code security and production vs libraries integration and security management.

It is two different tasks, but handling some house-made code security for functionalities has some advantages related to *control*: the code is in your hand, if there is a vulnerability in it, it is your duty to maintain a decent security level and to prevent vulnerabilities within your development team.

In many programming languages, however, external packages exists for classic software functions, tooling, common programming utilities... Developers might be unpleased if they have to do themselves something that already exists (*don't reinvent the wheel*). In fact, in a lot of software it is not uncommon that a vast percentage of the total lines of codes total count comes from external modules.

The security duties then switch from code production to package choosing (since it is your team duty to select modules that are not vulnerable and well maintained, and they might debate that they have better security awareness than the external modules developers...) and management. Because if an external module vulnerability is disclosed, it is then your goal to stop using it and replace it with a patched version, or eventually switch to another external module and if none of these is applicable, re-implement the module functionalities.

In recent years with every package management system (FOSS or not, npm, maven central, pip…) there were some modules that had some reported security vulnerabilities at some point in time. Most of the time there is a problem when project managers loose the dependencies tracking or updates and push into production vulnerable software that they can't even maintain secured.

Some automated solutions exist to update external modules automatically, which can save time, but most of the time it is a task that require at least someone in charge.